# Connecting to remote my Sql shows me access denied for user azerty@41.175.10.32 ( Using Password : Yes )

Tags: mysql, database, delphi, delphi-2010

Everything worked fine, When I configure the `TMySqlConnection` Driver to connect on the Local computer using WAMP local server, but when trying to configure the driver to connect to a remote MySQL server, I got an error.

> aceess denied for user myuserna_me@41.175.10.32 ( Using password: yes)

How to fix the problem and force the host address to be the server's IP in which my SQL database is hosted.

credentials:

- HostName : mydomain-cdn.net
- PassWord : Hk*HjBc+SwXS
- Username : myusername
- Database : mydbname_main

Where 41.175.10.32 is my IP address (not the host address).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you haven't set up the `myuserna_me` user so that it has the right to connect to the DB from the `41.175.10.32` IP. mySQL user accounts do contain information from which IP given user may connect, it is also possible to use wildcard `%` for "without IP restrictions" access.
See "[Adding User Accounts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html)" topic in mySQL manual, it has some examples too.