# Access denied for user 'xxx'@'xxxxxx'

Tags: mysql, database

I have a software which communicate with a remote mysql server. After updating the mysql on the remote host I get

`2014-07-04 10:11:39.8750Access denied for user 'xxx'@'xxxxxx' (using password: YES)`

When I try to connect to the remote mysql from the computer that running the software with the same user and pass  there is no problem to connect.
Any ideas?

Comment: You need to grant access to the user in question with the IP or hostname from where its coming from to the given database it needs to access. Duplicate of [Connecting to remote my Sql shows me access denied for user azerty@41.175.10.32 ( Using Password : Yes )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711495/connecting-to-remote-my-sql-shows-me-access-denied-for-user-azerty41-175-10-32)

Comment: Just: `GRANT ALL ON db.* TO "xxx"@"xxxxxxx";`

Comment: A did what Jack suggest then flush privileges but still get access denied

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the user ACL. Probably your user currently can access to db only from localhost. You have to grant access from the remote machine client IP.
Example:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%'
```

for all privileges from all ip addresses. You can also replace the '%' with you remote machine IP

Comment: Thats not the issue. As I said I can connect to the remote mysql with the credentials that the software I mention above use. But the software can't.

Comment: You say that you updated mysql. Maybe the new mysql version is no longer supported from your software client. try to check this...